# Oracle SQL Left join same table unknown amount of times

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, left-join

I have this table

```
| old  | new   | 
|------|-------| 
| a    | b     | 
| b    | c     | 
| d    | e     | 
| ...  | ...   | 
| aa   | bb    | 
| bb   | ff    | 
| ...  | ...   | 
| 11   | 33    | 
| 33   | 523   | 
| 523  | 4444  | 
| 4444 | 21444 |
```

The result I want to achieve is

```
| old  | newest | 
|------|--------| 
| a    | e      | 
| b    | e      | 
| d    | e      | 
| ...  |        | 
| aa   | ff     | 
| bb   | ff     | 
| ...  |        | 
| 11   | 21444  | 
| 33   | 21444  | 
| 523  | 21444  | 
| 4444 | 21444  |
```

I can hard code the query to get the result that I want.

```
SELECT 
   older.old,
   older.new,
   newer.new firstcol,
   newer1.new secondcol,
   …
   newerX-1.new secondlastcol,
   newerX.new lastcol

from Table older

Left join Table newer 
on older.old = newer.new

Left join Table newer1 
on newer.new = newer1.old

…

Left join Table newerX-1 
on newerX-2.new = newerX-1.old

Left join Table newerX 
on newerX-1.new = newerX.old;
```

and then just take the first value from the right that is not null.

Illustrated here:

```
| old  | new   | firstcol | secondcol | thirdcol | fourthcol |     | lastcol | 
|------|-------|----------|-----------|----------|-----------|-----|---------| 
| a    | b     | c        | e         | null     | null      | ... | null    | 
| b    | c     | e        | null      | null     | null      | ... | null    | 
| d    | e     | null     | null      | null     | null      | ... | null    | 
| ...  | ...   | ...      | ...       | ...      | ...       | ... | null    | 
| aa   | bb    | ff       | null      | null     | null      | ... | null    | 
| bb   | ff    | null     | null      | null     | null      | ... | null    | 
| ...  | ...   | ...      | ...       | ...      | ...       | ... | null    | 
| 11   | 33    | 523      | 4444      | 21444    | null      | ... | null    | 
| 33   | 523   | 4444     | 21444     | null     | null      | ... | null    | 
| 523  | 4444  | 21444    | null      | null     | null      | ... | null    | 
| 4444 | 21444 | null     | null      | null     | null      | ... | null    |
```

The problem is that the length of "the replacement chain" is always changing (Can vary from 10 to 100).

There must be a better way to do this?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to them.)

Comment: Okay I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a recursive query. Something like this:

```
with cte (old, new, lev) as
(
  select old, new, 1 as lev from mytable
  union all
  select m.old, cte.new, cte.lev + 1
  from mytable m
  join cte on cte.old = m.new
)
select old, max(new) keep (dense_rank last order by lev) as new
from cte
group by old
order by old;
```

The recursive CTE creates all iterations (you can see this by replacing the query by `select * from cte`). And in the final query we get the last `new` per `old` with Oracle's `KEEP LAST`.

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/CHTG34988

Comment: Got this error message: "ORA-32044: cycle detected while executing recursive WITH query". I feel like you are getting close.

Comment: Thank you ! I had some duplicate values spooking. This is indeed correct.

Comment: Follow up question. If there are cycles in the table how can you detect them ? 
Rexter example: http://rextester.com/TBTOX41926

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand how you group your rows to determine different "newest" values.  Are these the groupings you want based on the `old` field?

Group 1 - one letter (a, b, d)
Group 2 - two letters (aa, bb)
Group 3 - any number (11, 33, 523, 4444)

Is this correct?  If so, you just need to group them by an expression and then use a window function `MAX()`.  Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  "old",
  MAX() OVER(PARTITION BY MyGrouping) AS newest
FROM (
  SELECT 
    "old",
    CASE 
      WHEN NOT IS_NUMERIC("old") THEN 'string' || CHAR_LENGTH("old") -- If string, group by string length
      ELSE 'number' -- Otherwise, group as a number
    END AS MyGrouping
  FROM MyTable
) src
```

I don't know if Oracle has equivalents of the `IS_NUMERIC` and `CHAR_LENGTH` functions, so you need to check on that.  If not, replace that expression with something similar, like this:

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/isnumeric.php

Comment: In Oracle 12.2, there is a new function, validate_conversion, for checking datatypes, https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD.  Before 12.2, there is no built in function.

Comment: This has nothing to do with groupings.


Example: 
if I have let's say "material" 'b' and I want to know the newest "material"? I follow the chain 'b' -> 'd' -> 'e'.

if I have let's say "material" '33' and I want to know the newest "material"? in this case it's '21444'.