# Oracle SQL Left join same table unknown amount of times with cycles

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, cycle

This is follow up question to my previous question:  [Oracle SQL Left join same table unknown amount of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989579/oracle-sql-left-join-same-table-unknown-amount-of-times)

Let's say I have this dataset

```
| old  | new   | 
|------|-------| 
| a    | b     | 
| b    | c     | 
| d    | e     | 
| e    | a     | <- Here is a cycle 
| ...  | ...   | 
| aa   | bb    | 
| bb   | ff    | 
| ...  | ...   | 
| 11   | 33    | 
| 33   | 523   | 
| 523  | 4444  | 
| 4444 | 33    | <- another cycle
```

because of the cycles oracle returns this error: 
**"ORA-32044: cycle detected while executing recursive WITH query"**

I want to break the recursive cycle and detect the rows that are causing the cycle

In the following it's possible to break the cycle with "<"

```
with numbers(val) as (
select 1 as val from dual
union all
select val + 1 from numbers
where val < 5 
)
select val from numbers
```

I tried the following in: http://rextester.com/ITB3407

Same code here:

```
with cte (old, new, lev) as
(
  select old, new, 1 as lev from mytable
  union all
  select m.old, cte.new, cte.lev + 1
  from mytable m
  join cte on cte.old = m.new
  where cte.lev < 6
)
select old, max(new) keep (dense_rank last order by lev) as new
from cte
group by old
order by old;
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387957/getting-error-as-ora-32044-cycle-detected-while-executing-recursive-with-query

Comment: How can you decide which row is cycle if you don't explicitly a `start row`? For e.g, if you start from `b, c` then `a, b` is cycle; if you start from `e, a` then `a, b` is cycle? It also means that if you have cycle then any **new** value could be the **newest** value in your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `CYCLE` clause. By specifying this clause, the cycle is detected and the recursion stops

```
WITH cte (OLD, NEW, lev)
     AS (SELECT OLD, NEW, 1 AS lev FROM mytable
         UNION ALL
         SELECT m.old, cte.new, cte.lev + 1
           FROM mytable m JOIN cte ON cte.old = m.new
                                        )
  CYCLE OLD SET cycle TO 1 DEFAULT 0
  SELECT OLD, MAX (NEW) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY lev)
    FROM cte
GROUP BY OLD
ORDER BY OLD;
```

[**REXTESTER**](http://rextester.com/live/HZZQ71586)